# Missing APNs certificate. Upload the certificate in Settings

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not able to send the push notification.
Every thing is seems fine but when I am sending the notification to any of the iOS device its giving the error that `Missing APNs certificate. Upload the certificate in Settings`

I am using the Cordova and and xCode to create the build.
I am able to get the FCM registration token while opening the device but not able to send the notification on that token.

I have already uploaded the p12 certificate on the Firebase.

Comment: I'm having the same issue this morning. In my case, I revoked the certificate, and uploaded a new one (valid). Now FCM fails and gives me this error message.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue in today morning.

The problem that the device was registered once and unregistered again is because the GCM environment and the certificate (key) we use for development and production environment. During our development, we use iOS development certificate to install the app on iOS device. If it is development certificate, GCM sandbox should be used.

I just Add the `'gcmSandbox' : 'true'` for iOS and it start working.

here is the my updated code:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679"
    },
    ios: {
    alert: "true",
    badge: "true",
    sound: "true",
    gcmSandbox: "true",
    senderID: "12345679"

},
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

These discussion will help you to understand in detail.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/567

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/548

I hope this will help you. :)